# howto make secure ajax requests with jquery?

Tags: ajax, security, jquery

i'm working on a project which works very much with ajax (made via jquery).

how we want to secure the project more and set it up with https. now i have two questions:

1. is it possible to make ajax requests to a https site with all the security features?
2. is it possible to make normal (http) ajax requests but with a certain security level like authentification? that the requests always have something like a username and a one time password? (but anyway this would be bad because the requests would be send in plaintext)

need to know more about secure ajax requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do https requests.

The only requirement is that you domain is also in HTTPs, and the main website URL must be in HTTPS too.

If you choose to use HTTPS, then you won't be able to use HTTP anymore, as it will be considered as 2 differents domains.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it's possible to make ajax requests through HTTPS.
2. Sure, take a look at [aSSL](http://assl.sullof.com/assl/).

You should also read up on the [white papers by OpenAjax Alliance on Ajax and Mashup Security](http://www.openajax.org/whitepapers/Ajax%20and%20Mashup%20Security.php).